# AWS Lambda NodeJS access result of Dynamo DB query from outer function

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query Dynomo DB table and I want to go through over the resulting items in a function in my AWS Lambda. I am not able to extract result from Dynamo DB query. It is inside the closure, I am able to console log it, but I am not able to assign it for any variable in the scope of outer function.
What should I do to get it outside?

```
function check(id) {

    //build params
    let params = {
        TableName: 'demo_table',
        KeyConditionExpression: #key =: id,
        Limit: 5,
        ScanIndexForward: false,
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            #key: process.env.PRIMARYKEY
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            : id: id
        }
    };

    //query ddb
    let result = {};

    ddb.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("AN ERROR OCCURED\n");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //How to copy the data from here to outside??
            //I can console log and see the data
            result = data;
        }

    });
    console.log(result); //returns {}
}
```

Comment: you can use async, callback or promise to resolve this issue.

Comment: I declared result outside the check(). Made check async. Added await before ddb.query. It still returns me empty braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const check = async (id) => {

//build params
let params = {
    TableName: 'demo_table',
    KeyConditionExpression: #key =: id,
    Limit: 5,
    ScanIndexForward: false,
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        #
        key: process.env.PRIMARYKEY
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        : id: id
    }
};



let result = await new Promise((resolve, rejects) => {
    ddb.query(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) rejects(err)
        resolve(data)
    });
})


console.log(result); //returns {}
}
```

By using promises you can get the data. database read is an asyncronous operation.